# Understanding the operation of map function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I came across the following example from the book "Fast Processing with Spark" by Holden Karau. I did not understand what the following line of code does in the program:

```
val splitLines = inFile.map(line => {
val reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(line))
reader.readNext()
})
val numericData = splitLines.map(line => line.map(_.toDouble))
val summedData = numericData.map(row => row.sum)
```

The program is :

```
package pandaspark.examples
import spark.SparkContext
import spark.SparkContext._
import spark.SparkFiles;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader
import java.io.StringReader
object LoadCsvExample {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
  if (args.length != 2) {
    System.err.println("Usage: LoadCsvExample <master>
      <inputfile>")
    System.exit(1)
  }

 val master = args(0)
 val inputFile = args(1)
 val sc = new SparkContext(master, "Load CSV Example",
 System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"),
 Seq(System.getenv("JARS")))
 sc.addFile(inputFile)
 val inFile = sc.textFile(inputFile)
 val splitLines = inFile.map(line => {
 val reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(line))
 reader.readNext()
 })
val numericData = splitLines.map(line => line.map(_.toDouble))
val summedData = numericData.map(row => row.sum)
println(summedData.collect().mkString(","))
}
}
```

I briefly know the functionality of the above program. It  parses the input
CSV and sums all the rows. But how exactly those 3 lines of code work to achieve is what I am unable to understand.

Also could anyone explain how the output would change if those lines are replaced with flatMap? Like:

```
val splitLines = inFile.flatMap(line => {
val reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(line))
reader.readNext()
})
val numericData = splitLines.flatMap(line => line.map(_.toDouble))
val summedData = numericData.map(row => row.sum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val splitLines = inFile.map(line => {
val reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(line))
reader.readNext()
})
val numericData = splitLines.map(line => line.map(_.toDouble))
val summedData = numericData.map(row => row.sum)
```

so in this code is basically reading a CSV file data and adding it's value.
suppose your CSV file is something like -

```
10,12,13
1,2,3,4
1,2
```

so here inFile we are fetching a data from CSV file like -

```
val inFile = sc.textFile("your CSV file path")
```

so Here inFile is an RDD Which has text formatted data.
and when you apply collect on it then it will look like this -

```
Array[String] = Array(10,12,13 , 1,2,3,4 , 1,2)
```

and when you apply map over it then you will find -

```
line = 10,12,13
line = 1,2,3,4
line = 1,2
```

and for reading this data in CSV format it is using -

```
val reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(line))
reader.readNext()
```

so after reading data in CSV format, splitLines look like -

```
Array(
Array(10,12,13), 
Array(1,2,3,4), 
Array(1,2)
)
```

on splitLines, it's applying

```
splitLines.map(line => line.map(_.toDouble))
```

here in line you will get Array(10,12,13) and after it, it's using

```
line.map(_.toDouble)
```

so it's changing all elements type from string to Double.
so in numericData you will get same

```
Array(Array(10.0, 12.0, 13.0), Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0), Array(1.0, 2.0))
```

but all elements now in form of Double

and it's applying the sum of the individual row or array so answer something like -
    Array(35.0, 10.0, 3.0)

you will get it when you will apply susummedData.collect()

Comment: Could you please tell how would the output change if I used flatMap instead?Like:                                                                                           
 val splitLines = inFile.flatMap(line => { val reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(line)) reader.readNext() })                     
 val numericData = splitLines.flatMap(line => line.map(_.toDouble))      
 val summedData = numericData.map(row => row.sum)

Comment: flatMap always remove internal rapper. so here we are getting the response like                                                                                                                                            
    Array(Array(10.0, 12.0, 13.0), Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0), Array(1.0, 2.0))
but when you apply flatMap instead map then your response will be like -   
    Array(10.0, 12.0, 13.0,1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0)      
you can see here beacuse of flatMap all the internal wrapper has been removed

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no any `flatMap` operation in your code sample, so title is misleading. But in general `map` called on collection returns new collection with function applied to each element of collection.

Going line by line through your code snippet:

```
val splitLines = inFile.map(line => {
val reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(line))
reader.readNext()
})
```

Type of `inFile` is `RDD[String]`. You take every such string, create csv reader out of it and call `readNext` (which returns array of strings). So at the end you will get `RDD[String[]]`.

```
val numericData = splitLines.map(line => line.map(_.toDouble))
```

A bit more tricky line with 2 maps operations nested. Again, you take each element of RDD collection (which is now `String[]`) and apply `_.toDouble` function to every element of `String[]`. At the end you will get `RDD[Double[]]`.

```
val summedData = numericData.map(row => row.sum)
```

You take elements of RDD and apply `sum` function to them. Since every element is `Double[]`, sum will produce single `Double` value. At the end you will get `RDD[Double]`.

Comment: Could you please tell  how would the output change if I used flatMap instead?Like:
val splitLines = inFile.flatMap(line => {
val reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(line))
reader.readNext()
})
val numericData = splitLines.flatMap(line => line.map(_.toDouble))
val summedData = numericData.map(row => row.sum)